# How Can I Solve this Image-to-speech Gradio App Error?

Tags: python, image, huggingface-transformers, speech, gradio

I have written an image-to-speech Python application but want to build a Gradio frontend for the app. Below is my Python code:

```
from transformers import pipeline 
from bark import SAMPLE_RATE, generate_audio, preload_models
from IPython.display import Audio
from PIL import Image
import gradio as gr
import numpy as np


def image_to_speech(image):
    # load text-to-speech bark models
    preload_models()

    captioner = pipeline("image-to-text",model = "Salesforce/blip-image-captioning-base")

    # Open the image using PIL
    image_pil = Image.open(image)

    result = captioner(image_pil)

    result = result[0]

    result_text = result["generated_text"]

    audio_array = generate_audio(result_text)

    return Audio(audio_array,rate = SAMPLE_RATE)

app = gr.Interface(image_to_speech, inputs = "image", outputs = "audio")

app.launch(debug = True)
```

However, when I pass an image to the app and run it to get an audio output, I get the error message below in my notebook:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/PIL/Image.py", line 2979, in open
    fp.seek(0)
AttributeError: 'numpy.ndarray' object has no attribute 'seek'

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/gradio/routes.py", line 439, in run_predict
    output = await app.get_blocks().process_api(
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/gradio/blocks.py", line 1389, in process_api
    result = await self.call_function(
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/gradio/blocks.py", line 1094, in call_function
    prediction = await anyio.to_thread.run_sync(
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/anyio/to_thread.py", line 33, in run_sync
    return await get_asynclib().run_sync_in_worker_thread(
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/anyio/_backends/_asyncio.py", line 877, in run_sync_in_worker_thread
    return await future
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/anyio/_backends/_asyncio.py", line 807, in run
    result = context.run(func, *args)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/gradio/utils.py", line 704, in wrapper
    response = f(*args, **kwargs)
  File "<ipython-input-2-a32bc59fff0d>", line 17, in image_to_speech
    image_pil = Image.open(image)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/PIL/Image.py", line 2981, in open
    fp = io.BytesIO(fp.read())
AttributeError: 'numpy.ndarray' object has no attribute 'read'
```

I have exhausted all the tricks I know in the books and yet the problem persists. I do not know where to go from here. ChatGPT couldn't help either. Please, I need your help. Thank you!